# Electron JS with root privileges

Tags: electron, root, pcap

I'm writting an ElectronJS app using pcap. When I start the app by `npm start`, I've got an error saying that operation is not permitted. It was indeed expected as pcap requires root privileges. Problem is I cannot either launch the app with `sudo npm start --no-sandbox`.
What's more, if I build the project using electron-builder, I can start the AppImage with `sudo ./y-1.0.0.AppImage --no-sandbox` , but I've got display errors and the browser window did not appears, enven if pcap is working. I also tried `sudo -E ./y-1.0.0.AppImage --no-sandbox` with no success.

Any idea? Thanks for your help!

Comment: sounds kinda like [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/31123)

Comment: You're right, that was the same problem. Thanks to adding the right option, the command `sudo npm start -- --no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox` solves the graphical problem. Now, the only eror remaining is: `[23392:1202/104256.255227:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")`. There are several lines of that error...